# Div to fit browser window size

Tags: jquery, css, html, cross-browser

I want to create a `div` which fits the browser window, but has content underneath which is visible when scrolling.

I don't want the div to be fixed, but I want it to be the same size as the browser window, and when re-sizing.

I'm sure the solution is very simple, but my mind has gone blank.

Below is what I'd like it to look like.

[image: Browser screenshot]

Comment: Your code, that have you tried ..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply by setting `height: 100%`

But remember also about setting `html`, `body` to `100%` and all parents of your div.

For example if you have:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="height100"></div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Your css should look like this:

```
html, body, #wrapper, #height100 {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: "(...) but has content underneath which is visible when scrolling."

Comment: @silentw it will has content underneath

Answer (score 1):

**[CHECK THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GHEtL/)**

```
<div class='viewport'>
    <ul>
             <li>Nav</li>
             <li>Nav</li>
             <li>Nav</li>
             <li>Nav</li>
         </ul>
    <div class='belowviewport'>Content</div>
<div>


body { margin: 0;}
.viewport{
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background: blue;
}
.belowviewport {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    top:100%; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I think this is what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/NDrSm/

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
}

div.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body{
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    margin : 0
}
#content{
   height : 100%;
   width : 100%;
}
```

-1 to your question from me. Because this is not a new requirement. Google once before asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple jQuery solution:

```
function calc() {
    var $window = $(window),
        $nav = $('nav'),
        $content = $('#content');
    $content.height($window.height() - $nav.height());
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hY8Th/)</kbd>

*PS: You can actually define an min-height for the content div via css.*

## **EDIT:**

If you plan on using plain JavaScript, here is a solution:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

w.onload = calc();
w.onresize = calc();

function calc() {
    var nav = d.getElementById('nav'),
        content = d.getElementById('content');
    content.style.height = (getWindowHeight() - nav.clientHeight) + 'px';
}

function getWindowHeight() {
    return w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hY8Th/1/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**DEMO WITH MIN-HEIGHT 300px**](http://jsfiddle.net/hY8Th/2/)</kbd>